# Как исправить ошибку тайпскрипта?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

Получаю данные по апи с популярными крипто-монетами на страницу, хотел сделать так чтоб при нажатии на какую-то из них открывалась страница с более подробным описанием и столкнулся с тем что получаю ошибку:

> Type '{ children: Element; to: string; key: string; element: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & RefAttributes'.
> Property 'element' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & RefAttributes'.

```js
/*Мой App.tsx с роутингом, тут все работает хорошо:*/

<Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Coins coins={coins} />} />
        <Route path="/coin" element={<Coin />}>
          <Route path=":coinId" element={<Coin />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Ошибку получаю уже в своем компоненте Coins (в нем принимаю пропсы и мапом вывожу все монеты)

```js
export default function Coins(props: IPropsCoins) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="description-row">
        {props.coins.map((coins) => {
          return (
            <Link to={`/coin/${coins.id}`} key={coins.id} element={<Coin />}>
              <CoinItem coins={coins} />
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Ошибкой подсвечивает "element", текст ошибки вставил выше, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что бы понять, что не так и почему ругается, надо смотреть ваши типы. т.е. компонент имеет тип А а вы передаете тип Б

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Property 'element' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & RefAttributes'.

Пользуясь переводчиком получаем:

> Свойство «element» не существует для типа «IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & RefAttributes».

`<Link to={`/coin/${coins.id}`} key={coins.id} element={<Coin />}>`

**element** тут лишний